# Laravel REST API call returns dummy data with status 200

Tags: php, json, rest, api, laravel

I am working on making mobile application backend apis. The api I am working on now is just getting user information.
I am testing the api with Postman app.

When I call the api on the postman, it returns JSON data successfully, but sometimes it returns dummy data for same api call.
And when I try again, it returns correct JSON data.

I am attaching two screens.
Here is the issue:
[image]

Below shows correct response:

[image]

I am using Laravel5.1 and OAuth2 authentication module(lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) from Github.
Server is hosted on Bluehost.

Here is laravel code:

```
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($id = null)
    {
        if($id == null) {
            $my_id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
            return User::find($my_id);
        }
        else
            return User::find($id);
    }
```

I am struggling with this issue for a week and please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That isn't _dummy data_ in the first screenshot. It's probably an error. Check the laravel *log file* whenever you get that output. It would probably point to the actual error.

Comment: Hello @linuxartisan, I checked laravel log but there are no logs for the api issue. I deleted the laravel.log and called the api, but no logs recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it has something to do with Incapsula. I don't know if this is something you setup, or if it is setup by your host, but the traffic to your website is going through Incapsula. Some of your POSTMAN requests are getting through fine, but some of them are being blocked by Incapsula, probably because they look like someone trying to scrape your site.

If you have control over this, you may want to whitelist your local IP while developing and testing.

Comment: Yes, the result contains <iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe> on its body.

Comment: Hello @patricus, I contacted Bluehost, but they are not supporting Incapsula.

Comment: Hello @patricus, do you know how to setup/uninstall Incapsula?

Comment: @PaulStein No, I have no experience with it. But, it looks like you need to contact whoever setup your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Bluehost is not providing incapsula service, but the server DNS is allocated on Godaddy before moving and Godaddy setup incapsula.
I have parking domain on Bluehost and replacing the domain address on my codes, the issues disappeared.